# Prove that any hyperplane and halfspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, linear-programming

> $a)$ Prove that a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Recall that a hyperplane is a set of the form $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a^Tx= b\}$ for some vector $a$ and scalar $b$.
>
> $b)$ Prove that a halfspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Recall that a halfspace is a set of the form $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a^Tx\ge b\}$ for some vector $a$ and scalar $b$.

$a)$

Proof.

Let $S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a^Tx= b\},x_0,x_1\in S$, we have

$$a^Tx_0=a^Tx_1=b$$

$\text{WTS }x_3:=tx_0+(1-t)x_1\in S$ where $t\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{R}$

Since $a^T$ is a linear tranformation

$$a^T(x_3)=ta^Tx_0+a^Tx_1-ta^Tx_1=b$$

And

$$a^T(x_3)=b\rightarrow x_3\in S$$

Which proves any convex combination of any two points in $S$ is also in $S$ $\tag*{$\square$}$

$\color{lightgrey}{\text{The proof for $b)$ is almost same as $a)$}}$

$b)$

Proof.

Let $S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a^Tx\ge b\},x_0,x_1\in S$, we have

$$a^Tx_0\ge b \wedge a^Tx_1\ge b$$

$\text{WTS }x_3:=tx_0+(1-t)x_1\in S$ where $t\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{R}$

Since $a^T$ is a linear tranformation

$$a^T(x_3)=ta^Tx_0+a^Tx_1-ta^Tx_1\ge b$$

And

$$a^T(x_3)\ge b\rightarrow x_3\in S$$

Which proves any convex combination of any two points in $S$ is also in $S$ $\tag*{$\square$}$

Is my proofs correct, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: $\implies$ for implications, not $\to$

Comment: In my opinion, the proof of b) needs more justification. How do you conclude that $t a^T x_0 + a^T x_1 - t a^T x_1 \geq b$? Otherwise, looks good!